# POST request sent twice using fetch js

Tags: javascript

I call a POST method with javascript using fetch, Checked my server logs and see these lines:

```
2020-02-08,14:07:21 [WARNING] (web.py:web:1618): 400 POST /login (::1): Missing argument username
2020-02-08,14:07:21 [WARNING] (web.py:web:2106): 400 POST /login (::1) 8.64ms
...
2020-02-08,14:07:21 [DEBUG] (base_handler.py:base_handler:123): Attempted Sign-in by asdas
2020-02-08,14:07:21 [INFO] (web.py:web:2106): 200 POST /login (::1) 6.07ms
```

Here is the js which sends the request and then uses the response to add text to the page if login is unsuccessful:

```js
function ready(){

    function pwdSubmission(){
        const url = window.location.href;
        var result = document.getElementById("result-text");
        var username = document.getElementById("user").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
        fetch(url, {method:"post", headers:{ 
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"},
        body:{"username":username, "password":password}}
        ).then(function(data){
        if (data.status !== 200){
            result.style.color = '#d9534f';
        }
        return data.json()
        }).then(data =>
        result.innerText = data["message"])
    }

    var postbtn = document.getElementById("post-btn");
    postbtn.addEventListener("click", pwdSubmission)
}
```

So why is the POST sent twice and the first time it doesn't include the arguments.

UPDATE 
 My server have no problem grabbing the arguments from the body even without stringify but there is no body in the first request, only the second, so I get an error which sends json back

Comment: Can you post the contents of the request body from the Network Tab in the Developer Tools?

Comment: It looks like the last line with the request status is solely reporting the timing, which in that case was 11.32ms. Doesn't look like the request happened twice.

Comment: "see these two lines" - posts 4 lines ...

Comment: No, there are two POST time states being printed

Answer (score 0):

The `body` param isn't correct.  You're passing an object when it should be a JSON string.

```
body:JSON.stringify({username:username, password:password}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. My inputs were wrapped in a `form` tag and the button was defaulting to a form submit so I removed those tags and it only sends once now.

Answer (score 0):

Your body data type must match your "Content-Type" header ("application/json" in your case).

Using ES6 object shorthand you could do...

```
body: JSON.stringify({username, password})
```